# Balancing a non-BST

Tags: data-structures, tree, binary-tree, binary-search-tree, avl-tree

On a recent test in Algorithms course I got a task to use methods used to rebalance an AVL tree, to balance some  given binary tree. The problem is, what if that tree is not BST? Does it makes sense to use rotations? I mean, you could use them but there seems to be no way to balance such tree before "fixing" it I.e. making it a BST.

If this is possible, is there a situation in which this would be useful? I can't seem to find any real logic behind this, other than to bring in confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This really depends on what the tree represents. Tree rotations are a natural idea when talking about binary search trees because they represent a way of reshaping the tree while preserving the binary search property. In other trees, this might not be possible. For example, in a [k-d tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-d_tree), which acts somewhat like a BST but works in higher dimensions, rotations aren't possible because a node's level in the tree determines how comparisons against that node works. However, it is possible to rebalance k-d trees by removing a subtree and rebuilding it from scratch. (This idea also can be used in regular BSTs; look up the [scapegoat tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scapegoat_tree) for details).

In some other tree structures, such as parse trees, the idea of a rotation doesn't make sense at all because the tree encodes a hierarchy rather than an ordering. In those cases, a tree may be fundamentally imbalanced because it's trying to represent something that itself is fundamentally imbalanced.

So in general, no, there's no way to generalize tree rotations to non-BSTs, though in certain circumstances it may be possible to talk about more- and less-balanced trees.

Answer (score 0):

The real sense of using BST lies in O(logn) search and replace each element.
If the tree is not binary, then search and replacement are costly, thats the reason why we use AVL to balance as BST, which becomes a Linked List in its worst case.

The applications also include memory management, process scheduling somtimes. And many more.